# Bijective continuous map between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, continuity

I am currently attending a course on point-set topology and fundamental group. Today we proved in class that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not homeomorphic with their normal Hausdorff topologies. I also learned from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514354/proof-of-non-existence-of-a-continuous-bijection-between-mathbbr-and-math) question that there is in fact no continuous bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am wondering, what happens when we consider other topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$? For example, in our course, we discussed cofinite and cocountable topologies, which I denote by $\tau_f$ and $\tau_c$ respectively.

I am wondering, are there continuous bijections between $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_c)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, \tau_f)$? What about between $(\mathbb{R}^2, \tau_c)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_f)$?

Comment: The cofinite and cocountable topologies reduce it to a question of cardinality. Any injective map between two spaces, both endowed with the cofinite topology, or both endowed with the cocountable topology, is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I agree. But I am asking if there is a continuous bijection from a cocountable topology to a cofinite topology.

Comment: Well, the cocountable topology on $X$ is finer than the cofinite topology on $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I see, the question is trivial, thanks a lot!