# Invertible functions in $ R^m$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

The definition of an invertible function that my book (Apostol's Mathematical Analysis) gives is:

A function $f:S \to\mathbf{R}^n$, where $S$ is open in $\mathbf{R}^n$, has a unique inverse if $f$ is $C^1$ on $S$ and $J_f(\mathbf{a})\not = 0$ on $S$ (where $J_f(\mathbf{a})$ is the Jacobian determinant of $f$ at $\mathbf{a}$).

This definition is fine for functions from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$, but what about for $g:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^m$? In this case the determinant does not exist, so this theorem does not apply! How do I determine whether such a $g$ is invertible?

Also, for a function $f$ between topologies we know that $f$ has an inverse if it is bijective - does that apply here as well? Is it sufficent to show that $g$ is bijective? Is the inverse of $g$ always unique?

Comment: *for a function f  between topologies we know that f  has an inverse if it is bijective*: I might be misunderstanding what you mean here, but a even a continuous bijection may not have a continuous inverse. Inverse functions are always unique, though.

Comment: Perhaps I am misremembering, but I seem to recall that if $f:A\to B$ is injective then it has a right inverse (not necessarily continuous) and if $f$ is surjective then it has a right inverse (also not necessarily continuous). So if $f$ is bijective then it has a good-old-fashioned inverse $g$ such that $g\circ f(x) = x$ and $f\circ g(y) = y$.

Comment: In general, if you are talking about sets, then yes, a *set function* has an inverse iff it is bijective. When you are talking about *topological spaces* and continuous maps between them, you would call a continuous map $f$ invertible iff there is a continuous map $g$ such that $fg$ and $gf$ are identities on their respective spaces. (This implies that they are bijections.) But in general, a continuous bijection may not have a continuous inverse, and so it may not be invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of different dimensions, you can't normally hope for an inverse function, if you are thinking of the problem in an analytic/differential set-up. In fact, it is a simple consequence of [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) that if $g$ is $C^1$, then the image of $g$ will have Lebesgue measure zero if $m > n$, so it will be rather "small". In particular, $g^{-1}$ won't make sense on any open set.

On the other hand, if the derivative of $g$ (the Jacobian matrix, or the tangent map, if you prefer) has full rank, i.e. $n$ (assuming $m > n$), then the image of $g$ will locally be manifold, and $g$ will locally be invertible. By this I mean that for a point $x \in R^n$, you can find a small neighbourhood, such that $g$ restricted to that neigbourhood maps it to bijectively and smoothly to its image.

Comment: "if the derivative of $g$ has full rank, then [...] g will locally be invertible." That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: One question, though: does the Jacobian having full rank tell me anything about the inverse being $C^1$? In your last sentence, did you mean "such that _the inverse of $g$_ restricted to that neigbourhood maps bijectively and smoothly to its image."?

Comment: @alexvas: What I meant was: for any $x \in R^n$, you can find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $g:\ U \to g(U)$ is smooth and bijective, and $g^{-1}:\ g(U) \to U$ is smooth and bijective (smooth = as smooth as $g$ is assumed to be). Mind that $g(U)$ is a submanifold of $R^m$, with dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a nice smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is like a loop de loop. You would have a two-to-one point.

Consider a nice smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^1$. Locally you will have smashed a two-dimensional vector space into a one-dimensional (or lower) space, so there are many-to-one points.

Comment: Sure - around the point that breaks injectivity the function would not be invertible (this is consistent with bijective => invertible), but there are plenty of non-bijective maps from $\mathbf{R}^1$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$ that are locally invertible. For instance, any graph is invertible in any ball where it is bijective. I'm trying to find the necessary condition for a function between dimensions to be invertible.

Comment: @alexvas You should check out the examples given at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous

Comment: @alexvas I didn't interpret your question to be about _local_ invertibility, so my answer was meant to show that even very nice conditions on the map (smoothness) will not be able to guarantee invertibility if $m\neq n$.