# Inverse of function continuous at a point must be continuous at that point?

Tags: calculus

If a function $y = f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Suppose the function is invertible in a neigborhood of $x_0$. Is it true that the inverse function must be continuous at $y_0 = f(x_0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no in general (of course if $f$ is also differentiable there, then you could employ the inverse function theorem). Here is a link with many examples of continuous functions with inverses which are not continuous:

[Functions which are Continuous, but not Bicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous)

Comment: I should mention that many examples are of functions which are continuous everywhere, and invertible everywhere. You can simply restrict to a neighborhood of a correctly chosen point to get the local example you want.

Comment: The reason I ask this question is because I am reading the proof of the following proposition:

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I am reading the proof of the following proposition: "Suppose a continuous function is invertible near x_0 and is differentiable at x_0. If f'(x_0) is nonzero, then the inverse function is also differentiable at y_0 = f(x_0), with derivative 1/f'(x_0).". I wonder why it is necessary to specify that the function is continuous, because differentiability already imply continuity at x_0.

Comment: Yes, this is a good observation. It would be nice to have the inverse function of a continuous function automatically continuous, but alas, it's not.

Comment: I agree that the answer is no in general, but if $x_0$ is an interior point (of the domain of  $f$), then could the answer be true? Let just assume $f : U \subset \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ for simplicity. In the link you provided, the following example
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x \in [0,1) \\ x-1 & x \in [2,3] \end{cases}
$$
does not work because $x_0 = 2$ belongs to the boundary of the domain of $f$.