If $f$ is continuous at $a$, is $f^{-1}$ continuous at $f(a)$?
Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, and $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ an injective function. Let $a\in I$, and suppose that $f$ is continuous at $a$. Does it follow that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(a)$ ?
I know that if $f$ is assumed to be continuous in the entire $I$, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous. (Here I use the fact that $f$ is strictly monotonic.) With local continuity, however, I cannot use monotonic properties.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737465/42969

@MartinR Thanks for the link. It is interesting that it is not true in general, but here I'm assuming that the function is real-valued and defined on an interval, and none of the examples in the link seems to address this case.

A counterexample is as follows (now $I$ is open). Define $f:(-1,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x  & \text{ $x\neq \dfrac{1}{n}, x\neq n$} \\
\dfrac{1}{2n} &\text{$x=\dfrac{1}{n}$}\\
\dfrac{1}{2n+1} &\text{$x=n$}
\end{cases}$$
This function is injective (notice that points of the form $\dfrac{1}{n}$ map to even denominators and those of the form $n$ map to odd denominators), and continuous at $0$ as $x,\dfrac{1}{2n}\to 0$. Nonetheless, $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $f(0)=0$ because $f^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right)=n\not\to0.$

Is $n$ a positive integer? Is $f(1)$ $1/2$ or $1/3$ ?

I wonder if there are counterexamples when $I$ is an open interval of finite length or when $I=\mathbb{R}$.

$n$ is a positive integer. You could include $1$ in any of the two definitions, both lead to a counterexample. The above function can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$, just include all missing numbers in the first definition of $f$.

If you relax the condition that $I$ is open, then I believe this is a counterexample.
Let $f:[0,+\infty) $ be given by $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x  & \text{$x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\
-x & \text{$x \in \mathbb{I}\cap(0,1)$
}\\
\dfrac{1}{x} &\text{$x \in \mathbb{I}\cap(1,+\infty)$}
\end{cases}$$
This function is injective and continuous at $x=0$ as $x,-x\to 0$, but its inverse is not continuous at $f(0)=0$, because if $c\in \mathbb{I}\cap (0,1)$ then $f^{-1}(c)=\dfrac{1}{c}\in (1,+\infty)$.

I think one needs the assumption that $f$ is injective.
Because otherwise $f(a)$ might several pre-images. For example, assume $f$ is not injection, and for $a\neq b$, we have $f(a)=f(b)$.
Now consider open sets $U, V, W$ containing $a,b, f(a)$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\phi$. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, we have $f(U) \subset W$.
In order to be $f^{-1}$ to be continuous at $f(a)$, one must have both $f^{-1}(W) \subset U$ and $f^{-1}(W) \subset V$, which is impossible by our assumption that $U \cap V=\phi$.
So injective property is necessary.

I did assume injectivity. Please read the more detailed question posed below the title.

@ashpool, aah I see you assumed injective function. Anyway, this is necessary condition but not sufficient. In other words the answer to your question is NO, in general.
