# Function from Reals to Reals and has an inverset

Tags: analysis

We have seen in topology, that if a function is continuous and has an inverse, its inverse is not necessarily continuous. However the examples we had were from higher dimensions. So I've been thinking if this is also true for a function from the reals to reals. I couldn't find a counter example, and when I think geometrically, it's just a reflection on the line y=x. So I don't find any reason why the inverse wouldn't be continuous.
So I just wanted to verify if this claim is true or not. If it is I will try to prove, and if it isn't I would appreciate if someone can give counter example. Thanks!

Comment: Those functions exist, indeed: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous

Comment: Ok, I've got it, you need the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and injective, then the inverse map is also continuous.  For more advanced readers: Use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is locally compact.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: @DanielEscudero , then if I define f from the reals to the reals (In other words Rangef=R)  that is differentiable and has an inverse,then What I am saying is actually correct, right?

Comment: That's right. The inverse function theorem guarantee's that (always that $f$ is of class $C^1$ and the other hypothesis of the theorem hold). However, the theorem is still true with weaker hypothesis, as GEdgar noticed.