# Conditions on the Pre-Image

Tags: functions, continuity

> Preimage: the pre-image of a set $S\in\mathbb{R^m}$ under a mapping $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^m}$ is the set $f^{-1}(S)=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}:f(\vec{x})\in S\}$

My question is, does the mapping of $f$ have to be continuous? It seems intuitive, but the books I have don't state this explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure. I was just wondering if the definition should say $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Do you mean continuous in the sense of a topology? If so, note that invertibility does not guarantee continuity. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous

Comment: Continuity is not required to define the preimage; only invertibility is demanded.

Comment: So is this definition sufficient?

Comment: Assuming you meant $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, yes.

Comment: Note: Invertibility means that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$, i.e. $f^{-1}$ is also a function. Invertibility has nothing to do with the notion of pre-image.

Comment: The definition is just a definition, it places no other restrictions on $f$. To answer your question, no it does not need to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the function does not have to be continuous.

Look at the general setting where you have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$. $A$ and $B$ are sets. The pre-image of a set $B^\prime \subset B$ is $\{a\in A: f(a)\in B^\prime\}$, i.e. all elements from A that map into something in $B^\prime$.

If you know the function you can find the pre-image for any $B^\prime\subset B$ by figuring out what $\{a\in A: f(a)\in B^\prime\}$ is. You do not need to use any special property of $f$ to find a pre-image.