# Suppose $f$ is a continous bijection from compact metric space $X$ onto a metric space $Y$ . Then $f^{-1}$ is continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I read this theorem in rudin's book:

> Suppose $f$ is a continous bijection from compact metric space $X$ onto a metric space  $Y$ . Then $f^{-1}$ is continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$

I have some questions about hypothesis of the theorem..
Clearly bijection is required for the existence of inverse.
But we need compact? Do compact a necessary condition?

I want to see few counterexample,that if $X$ is not a compact metric space,then $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Thanks

Comment: I see an example in rudin mapping [0,$2\pi)$ onto unit circle.please give me some more examples other than this

Comment: $X$ discrete and $Y$ non-discrete so $X= \mathbb{N}$, $0\to 0$ and $n \to \frac1n$.

Comment: [Here's many examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68800/8157)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma then $Y={\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb N}$

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro that helps a lot thanks

Comment: And $\{0\}$ too is in $Y$

Comment: Thanks @Henno Brandsma