# Inverse of a continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

To prove for an open set, the inverse of a continuous function is continuous.

The proof is,

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. It is sufficient that $F^{-1}$ is the inverse of $F$ and $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open then $(F^{-1})^{-1}(W)$ is open. But

$(F^{-1})^{-1}(W)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\exists w\in W:F^{-1}(x)=w\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\exists w\in W:x=F(w)\}=F(W)$

and so $(F^{-1})^{-1}(W)$ is open if and only if $F(W)$ is open. Since $F(W)$ is open $W$ is open and $F$ is continuous.

This is the proof, I am unsure if it is correct also is there any example that can prove this?

Comment: This result is false, there's a bunch of counterexamples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous

Comment: You are correct that the preimage of a set $W$ under $F^{-1}$ (assuming it exists) equals the image set $F(W)$ but notice the definition says that a function $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(W)$ is open whenever $W$ is open. You seem to be committing some error of either confusing the direction of the implication in this definition or assuming without reason that $F$ is an open map.

Comment: You have no reason to believe that $F(W)$ will be open when you assume that $F$ is continuous (indeed, this is equivalent to what you are attempting to prove).  That would mean that $F^{-1}(W)$ would be guaranteed open.

Comment: You should also explicitly write down the assumption that $F$ is bijective, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @bitesizebo  if OP is asking about continuous bijections on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, this result is actually true.  Note that none of the counterexamples in the link are counterexamples to this claim.

Comment: to OP:  unless you know about compactness, this result is a little tough to get.  (There may be other, "friendlier" approaches that I do not know about.)  No matter what, I'm pretty sure any proof would need to make use of the (necessarily true) monotonicity of such a function.

Comment: Informal cliffs: Any continuous bijection with compact domain and Hausdorff codomain is a closed map. Every metric space is Hausdorff, and $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is locally compact Hausdorff. So if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bijection, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous at each point $y \in \mathbb{R}$ since $y$ has a compact neighborhood $K_y$  and $f{\restriction_{K_y}}$ is a closed map.

Comment: Or, $f([a,b])$ must be compact and connected, hence it must be $[c,d]$.  But $f$ is monotone (assume increasing), so $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$.  Delete ends, so $f(a,b) =(c,d)$.  Hence $f$ maps all open sets to open sets.