# 'Reversing the implication' on the delta-epsilon definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Is this logically valid? And if so, could someone please explain to me the name of the logical construct I'm performing (e.g. converse, contrapositive) as well as its mechanics? Please note that my training in mathemtical logic is basically non-existent.

If for any $\epsilon$ there exists some $\delta$ such that for all $x$, $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$ implies $l - \epsilon < f(x) < l + \epsilon$; then, for any $\delta$ there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $f(x)$, $l - \epsilon < f(x) < l + \epsilon$ implies $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$.

Ultimately I'm aiming to show that if $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = l$, then $\lim \limits_{y \to l} f^{-1}(y) = a$.

---

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Why would the function $f$ have an inverse? Take $f(x) = l$ for all $x$, for example.

Comment: I'm supposing $f$ does have an inverse.

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily reverse the quantifiers and reverse the implication. (As I pointed out, a constant function satisfies this second criterion.) It's certainly not true in general that a one-to-one continuous function must have a continuous inverse, so you're going to have to work harder than this — e.g., to show that the continuous function must be increasing or decreasing.

Comment: This is not logically valid - you reversed the implication, which in general cannot be done. If every apple is red, that doesn't mean that every red thing is an apple. ;)

Comment: for any δ there exists ϵ such that for all f(x), l−ϵ<f(x)<l+ϵ implies a−δ<x<a+δ"  that just plain isn't true.  Try the $\sin$ function for example.  For any $\delta$ let $k$ be an integer so that $2k\pi > \delta$. Let  $a=\frac \pi 2$ and $x = \frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$ and $l =1$ and $\epsilon$ be anything. Then $1-\epsilon <\sin x < 1+\epsilon$ is always true but $a-\delta < x < a+\delta$ is not.

Comment: If $f$ is bijective so that $f$ *has* an inverse and $f$ is continuous, then what you are trying to proved but you can't just reverse the conditionals to prove it.  You *will* have to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $|a-x|< \delta$ implies $|f^{-1}(x)-l| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous.