# Counterexamples to: If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, $Y$ is compact, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

It is a theorem that if $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection, $X$ is compact, then $g = f^{-1}$ is continuous. My professor asked us to find a counterexample to

> If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, $Y$ is compact, then $g = f^{-1}$ is continuous.

I do not like my counterexample so much because it uses the discrete metric. Are there other counterexamples?

**My Counterexample:** Let $X = [0, 1]$ with the Discrete metric, $Y = [0, 1]$ with the Euclidean metric, and let $f$ be the identity function.

Comment: @MariosGretsas Ah sorry I forgot to add that. I don't like my counterexample so much because it uses the discrete metric. Do you know of other counterexamples?

Comment: The smallest example seems to be the identity $f:X\to Y$ with $X=Y=\{1,2\}$, but $X$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$ and $Y$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, Y\}$.

Comment: @Ovi why not?? you counterexample is fine..if the inverse  function was continuous then $f$ would be a homeomorphism which is not the case here, since the metric spaces in your example are not homeomorphic..one is compact and the other is not.

Comment: @MariosGretsas It's just that if I can, I like to find counterexamples in more natural settings, such as functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $f$ is a bijection, you can always identify $X$ and $Y$ as sets. Then $f$ being continuous corresponds to the $X$-topology being finer than the $Y$-topology. The inverse not being continuous then means it's *strictly* finer. Thus all examples are akin to yours, but of course one doesn't need to go the whole way to use the finest topology of all on $X$. Take $X = Y = [0,1]$, the standard topology on $Y$, the lower limit topology on $X$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Since the OP used the `metric-spaces` tag, I suspect that he or she is not interested on that example.

Comment: Good point, @JoséCarlosSantos. Well, let's take $X = [0,1] \cup \mathopen{]} 2,3]$ and $Y = [0,2]$, both with the Euclidean metric.

Comment: That is true, unfortunately I don't know any topology.

Comment: @Ovi: given that, I've removed the `general-topology` tag.

Comment: See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68808/1508) to a similar question for a simple counter-example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah ok. I included it only because I thought topological people might be interested in answering this question.

Comment: @Ovi: In that case, and given that you don't know topology, you should have made clear in your question what kind of answer you were looking for. Otherwise, you were bound to get (and did get) answers that ignored the metric and gave you topological examples that cannot be derived from a metric, and which are likely useless to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine. Another example is to take $X=[0,2\pi)$ with the usual metric, and let $Y=S^1 = \{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$, the unit circle on the complex plane, with the usual metric (so the distance is measured on the plane, not along the circle).

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be given by $f(x) =e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$.

Now, $Y$ is closed and bounded, so it is compact. The function $f$ is a continuous bijection. But $f^{-1}$ is not continuous; if it were, then $f$ would be a homeomorphism, but removing a single point from $X$ (other than $0$) will disconnect $X$, and removing a single point from $Y$ does not. Alternatively, note that you cannot find a neighborhood of $1\in Y$ whose image lies inside the neighborhood $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ of $f^{-1}(1)=0$, since the image will contain points arbitrarily close to $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is fine, and quite simple and to the point.